# Is it possible to block or remove the children div when we use document.getElementByID for parent?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, slick.js

Is it possible to block or remove the children div(what we don't want to) when we use `document.getElementByID` for parent?

Here is my problem,
I have to duplicate the `Slider div` but I don't want to duplicate the `slider indicator` part.
I want to remove that part when duplicate.
The bad thing is `Slider indicator` is automatically generated from [slick-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick)

How should I do, any suggestion, please?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Since the DOM is dynamically generated by the plugin, simply duplicating it will likely not copy the UX over (event bindings and etc. might no longer work). You should instead instantiate a whole new slider instead.

Comment: - What do you mean by slier indicator?
- Any working example of your code?

Comment: Can you duplicate the markup contained by your `<div>` before adding Slick to it?